# Two XAMPP WordPress Installations, pointing one to a different URL, both not working correctly

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, xampp

I am running Windows 7 with an XAMPP local server with an installation of WordPress. I know this one works correctly, I've used it many times. I have a MySQL database for it and it sits in htdocs/wordpress.

Now, I have a contract in which I'm working for someone on another WordPress theme and would like to have this as a separate database and install. So, I make another folder in htdocs, let's call it folder2. I then create another database in MySQL, import the db I was given, and create a user to match the wp-config.php file of this install. No problem, except that it points to "localhost/folder2" and I need it to point to "local.folder2.com" to match the contractor.

So I hunt around the web and stumble on VirtualHosts for XAMPP. I go to /System32/drivers/etc/hosts and add the domain.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost ## Already here for XAMPP purposes
127.0.0.1 local.folder2.com ## URL to point localhost/folder2 towards
```

I then go to /xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf and add the necessary Virtual Host.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DirectoryRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/folder2"
    ServerName local.folder2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I restart Apache and MySQL. Problem is, now local.folder2.com works, but "localhost/wordpress/" does not. Using that URL directs me to the theme and db of folder2, baffling me entirely. Any ideas? I realize I can just work on one and not the other, but if I ever have more than one client at a time, switching it all out isn't going to work.

Comment: please post the contents of your hosts file

Comment: Did you also configure a apache virtual host for the original site?

Comment: @phil I have added the code you requested

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have tried that without any luck, though I will try it again if necessary maybe I missed something. I'm assuming that I would just copy and paste my other VirtualHost, direct it to htdocs/wordpress and place it above the current VirtualHost.

Comment: yes just copy/paste your other virtualhost but change the folder name and server name.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/vhosts/examples.html you definitely need two of them.

Comment: I got it to work. What I was trying the first time was putting localhost/wordpress in the VirtualHost. When I shortened it to simply localhost, I was able to use it properly. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, localhost stopped working because when another vhost was declared, no longer did the inherent connection between http://localhost.com and the directory "/htdocs" work. The solution was to add a vhost for the original location and then add a second one for the new location. Simple as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress" # Where I had localhost pointing
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.folder2.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/folder2"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/folder2">
        Allow Override All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Of course, you then must add them to your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 local.folder2.com
```

Restart Apache server, and you're good to go.